# Convert $y=x\tan \alpha$ in polar form.

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Convert $y=x\tan \alpha$ in polar form.

This is quite a trivial case. However, the answer given in the book does not seem quite correct to me. Here goes my solution.

> We know that in a polar system we can represent every point $P(x,y)$  as $P(r,\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle of $OP$ with the $x$ axis with origin $O$ and $r$ is the distance of $P$ from $O$. So, we can say $x=r\cos\theta $ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and hence $\tan \theta =y/x$. Now, we know that $\tan \alpha=y/x$ (given). Hence, $\theta=\alpha$. Now, substituting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ in the given equation we get now a so called polar equation.

However, the answer given in the book is $\sin\theta=\theta \cos\theta$. How is this possible? I am not quite getting it.

Comment: The solution $\sin \theta = \theta \cos \theta$ does not make sense to me either. Are you certain you did not misread the answer in the book?

Comment: We have solution $\theta = \alpha$ but also $\theta = \alpha+\pi$.

Comment: @cpiegore nope...it's the one given in the book...I guess it was a typo then...Thank you!...

Comment: The equation should reduce to$$y=x\tan(\alpha) \implies \sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta) \tan(\theta) \implies \tan(\theta)=\tan(\theta)$$and hence the solution provided by @GEdgar. $\tan(\theta)=\theta$ has infinitely many solutions, and its plot in polar coordinates is multiple rays extending from the origin, rather than two that point in the opposite directions.

Comment: @user170231 but since $\tan\theta=\tan\theta$ cannot be considered a polar equation in general so we have $\theta=\alpha$ as the polar equation,right? And yeah , since $\tan\theta=\tan(\pi+\theta)$  we have , $\theta+\pi=\alpha$ as another set of a polar equation , right?

Comment: An equation in polar coordinates does not have to depend on both $r$ and $\theta$. It's similar to how in Cartesian, we can assign $x=1$ or $x=-1$ to a vertical line in the plane, or $x^2=1$ to both lines simultaneously. In polar, $r=r_0$ describes a circle - the same distance $r_0$ from the origin, regardless of the value of $\theta$. Likewise, $\theta=\theta_0$ describes a ray - the same angle from the positive axis, regardless of the value of $r$. Then the plot $f(\theta)=0$ is the set of rays $\theta$ that satisfy this equation.

Comment: @user170231 I do get it now... Thank you so much...